# How to check if an email has a PDF attached, if it is there? how to display the Label name for all PDF attached file in Gmail using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using google app script, how to display the label name is pdf attached file in gmail?

Below is my code: i can able to display all the attachments in Logger.log(data);
but if i add `foo1.addToThread(threades);` im getting error like **Cannot convert Array to GmailThread. (line 69, file "Code")**

```
var Label= GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("AppScriptPDF");
     var threades = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
      for (i=0; i < threades.length; i++) {
       var msges = threades[i].getMessages();
        for (j=0; j < msges.length; j++) {
          var msg = msges[j];
          //Logger.log(msg);
          subject = msg.getSubject();
          //Logger.log(subject);
          var attch = msg.getAttachments()
          Logger.log( attch );
          for (var k = 0; k < attch.length; k++) {
            Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" ', msg.getSubject(), attch[k].getName());
            Label.addToThread(threades); //error
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: `threades` is an array with all threads that are in your inbox. You most likely need `threades[i]` to point to the specific thread that you're processing in your loop.

Comment: i want to display the threads `[AppScriptPDF]` wherever i found the pdf attachments

Comment: Thank you!..... i got the answer